Getting failed to fetch user profile error message in LinkedIn Authorization Code Flow (3-legged OAuth)
{
"statusCode": 500,
"message": "failed to fetch user profile",
"error": "InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile\n    at LinkedinStrategy. (/Users/danish/Documents/Project_X/project_x/usersX/node_modules/passport-linkedin-oauth2/lib/oauth2.js:57:19)\n    at passBackControl (/Users/danish/Documents/Project_X/project_x/usersX/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)\n    at IncomingMessage. (/Users/danish/Documents/Project_X/project_x/usersX/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)",
"timestamp": "2024-04-23T10:41:22.894Z",
"path": "/linkedin/callback?code=AQQa9TTNH9QeMZ9i1x8Fj2MCrjiIM57g3gnMqxDHeXZBewdkdg660FsDTMC_1tBtvBZn322M48OxZeWE0QStlIsMkCX-NyfeZeVqJIMCci3qMetGGj_U9LtTnybAXmgg-K1Unx5vLTYXm-FXBHmUOHu9JC_5O2kAJrOBPUG-zZRYfDZXVOk2L72aWSscso1LVGbp5uCNKggcTb3FaQU",
"method": "GET"
}
Below is the code of linkedIn Strategy
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy, Profile } from 'passport-linkedin-oauth2';

@Injectable()
export class LinkedinStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'linkedin'){

 constructor() {
    super({
        clientID: process.env.clientId,
        clientSecret: process.env.clientSecretId,
        callbackURL: process.env.callbackUrl, 
        scope: ['w_member_social', 'profile', 'email']
    });
}


async validate(accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: any): Promise<any> {
    console.log("Profile object:", profile);
    const { id, displayName, emails, photos } = profile;
    const user = {
        linkedinId: id,
        displayName,
        email: emails[0].value,
        photo: photos[0].value,
        accessToken,
        refreshToken,
    };
    return user;
}
}

